# Restore terminal windows after reboot

Tags: command-line

Is there any native or third-party tool that can restore all open terminal windows with their paths and command-line histories?

(NOT hibernation, I need this after the reboot (for example, after kernel update).)

Ubuntu 15.04, Unity shell.

Comment: you still get all the histories of your terminal commands by pressing up arrow key while using the terminal.

Comment: @RiashatRafat How? I open two or three term windows, work in them, then reboot machine, then open again - and there is NO history.

Comment: Just open the terminal and press up arrow key.

Comment: @riashat.rafat You don't understand: I had more than 1 terminal windows. And they had different command history.

Comment: yeah got it. The command history only shows history for the primary terminal not for the other terminals you opened subsequently.

Comment: @riashat.rafat And also I want to restore window with current directories.

Comment: One could put together a script that can open a number of terminal windows with whatever directories were open before . . .say a terminal window with 3 tabs open, will correspond to 3 terminal windows open.  I have an idea how that could be done. So far I can only think of running the script before rebooting to "memorize" those windows

Comment: **This is a worthwhile goal.** However, I have not researched it much as I use SecureCRT (COTS) instead. I also use a second machine (where needed) to host the terminal software and history (commands and output).

Comment: You need a short script, to capture history, called from the compile/restart script. But this would need to be run on each currently open session/window.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I don't know of anything existing like this. Secondly this is not a full answer, just parts, but I can't post a comment only answers.

I have done part of this, opening a gnome-terminal that resumes command history of a previous terminal session (I used this to capture commands during lengthy software testing). You don't need to capture the history separately, just specify what file the terminal should use. Call this script "myterm":

```
#/bin/bash

TERMDIR=~/.myterms
if [ ! -d $TERMDIR ] ; then
    mkdir $TERMDIR
fi

TERMUID=$1
if [ -z "$TERMUID" ] ; then
    # generate unique id for new terminal
    TERMUID="`basename \`tty\``-`date +'%s'`"
fi

HISTFILE=$TERMDIR/$TERMUID gnome-terminal
```

So executing myterm without an argument will place a new history file in TERMDIR. If later you execute myterm with one of the filenames in TERMDIR as an argument, it resumes that terminal's history. If you have a fixed set of terminals, you could also dispense with random uid generation and just use fixed names.

I realise you want to do a lot more than this, but one requirement is not clear to me - if you close a terminal manually, do you need to forget it? i.e. remove its history and not re-open on login? That may be a little tricky as I'm not sure how to detect manual closure as opposed to forced close during logout or shutdown.

Re-opening the terminals on login is simple enough by scanning TERMDIR; i.e. the existence of the history file flags that the terminal is needed.

More difficult is changing to the last working directory. Each child terminal knows its directory at the time it closes, via $PWD, but ofc  myterm can't read the child environment to write this to a store. No problem if it *is* known, however; just use

```
HISTFILE=$TERMDIR/$TERMUID gnome-terminal --working-directory somedir
```

You may need to write a monitor that runs during your user session to

1. detect when a terminal is closed and remove its history
2. periodically detect working directory and store this

depending on your requirements.